# Why does the world-wide COVID-19 death rate appear to be constant?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

[Total confirmed COVID-19 deaths per million people](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/total-covid-deaths-per-million?tab=chart&country=%7EOWID_WRL)
[image: Graph of deaths per million, showing linear growth line.]

One would normally expect the total deaths to be growing exponentially (going viral) or to be damping down and approaching a constant (zero new deaths).

But for the last three months, this graph appears almost linear, indicating a constant world-wide per capita death rate.

Linear growth is very rare in nature, so what factors account for the phenomenon in this case?

#### UPDATE:

It's nine months later, and except for a slight bend in November, the graph still looks very linear (and definitely not exponential as one might expect):

[image]

Comment: I would guess it's data discrepancy